# asp.net filter equivalent in angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, filter

I would like to invoke a service method on the beginning of each controller in angularjs. Just like I would do with a filter in asp.net mvc or a middleware in express/nodejs.

How should I do this in angularjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to go about doing this.
AngularJS provides events I can bind to.
`$onRouteChangeStart` and `$onRouteChangeFinish`

The first is triggered just before the route is changed, and the latter after (and after all dependencies are resolved for the controller).

So, in order to invoke code before each controller I would add something like this to my app:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [...]);

app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, target) {
        // CODE GOES HERE
    });
}]);
```